# Email template td width not accurate in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I am trying to set up the `<td>` in a `<tr>` of specific width. Each `<td>` is taking up a different width than specified.

Desired
left td - 80px
middle td - 400px
right td - 120px

Anny help appreciated.

Code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="padding content"
        style="padding-top:0;padding-right:25px;padding-bottom:20px;padding-left:25px;width:100%;text-align:left;font-size:15px;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="80">
                    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/MCXhwJB/authenticator-app-icon-large.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:50px;max-height:50;padding-right:10px;">
                </td>
                <td width="400">
                   <p style="font-size:18px;line-height: 23px;min-width:600px; display: inline;"><strong>Multi-Factor Authenticator (MFA)</strong></p>
                </td>
                <td width= "120" style="text-align: center;">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="-webkit-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; border:2px solid #007da5; border-radius: 10px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
                                 <a href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/" style="font-size:16px;   text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">
                                    <span style="color: #007da5; padding:10px 5px;">Learn More </span>
                                 </a>
                            </td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
                                
                            </tr>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've got a `min-width:600px` in there. Try removing that.

Also note padding should be taken into account in your overall width.

But the biggest consideration is, how do you think this is going to fit on mobiles with 300px width?

`<td>` elements do not need a width set if it should be variable. So the middle column should have no width set.

If you need further help, we will need to see the rest of the code, because that can be affecting layout.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post all your code, so I am making some assumptions mixed in with the fun facts of Outlook.

As an email client, it frequently skips the second name in a series of class names (`class="padding content"`). So if your class is actually, `.padded content`, add a - to close the gap. If it's two separate classes, try adding combining them for Outlook.

```
<tr>
  <td class="padding-content" style="padding-top:0;padding-right:25px;padding-bottom:20px;padding-left:25px;width:100%;text-align:left;font-size:15px;">
    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td width="80">*content*</td>
          <td width="400">*content*</td>
          <td width="120">*content*</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

If you are still unable to get the three to line up, try substituting the `<td>` in the nested tables to `<th>`.